# organiorganize layout like play store with httpasynctask result in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I followed a tutorial that creates a layout like  google playstore.
however I have an asynchronous method that returns me a list of cards with their category.I would like to know how I can display the list of categories and the cards of these categories knowing that certain categories have fewer cards than the others.

my activity class:

```
public class AccueilActivity extends Fragment implements AppCompatCallback {


    ArrayList<SectionData> allSampleData;
    public AccueilActivity() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        allSampleData = new ArrayList<SectionData>();
        createDummyData();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

      //  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_accueil, container, false);
       // return rootView ;


       RecyclerView my_recycler_view = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_accueil, container, false); //getView().findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_viewy);

       my_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);


        RecyclerViewDataAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewDataAdapter(getContext(), allSampleData);

        my_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));


        my_recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);

        return my_recycler_view;


    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

    }
```

@Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
        }
        public void createDummyData() {

```
        //String[] section = MainActivity.env_cat;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {

            SectionData dm = new SectionData();

            dm.setHeaderTitle("section"+i);

            ArrayList<SingleItem> singleItem = new ArrayList<SingleItem>();
            for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
                singleItem.add(new SingleItem("Item " + j, "URL " + j));
            }

            dm.setAllItemsInSection(singleItem);

            allSampleData.add(dm);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSupportActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSupportActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ActionMode onWindowStartingSupportActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

my asyncstask reponse:

```
0:object
cat_id:1
cat_lib:"shopping"
card_lib: "cat 1"
url:"https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/appicns/513/appicns_Chrome.png"

1:object
cat_id:1
cat_lib:"shopping"
card_lib: "cat 2"
url:"https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/appicns/513/appicns_Chrome.png"

2:object
cat_id:2
cat_lib:"spat"
card_lib: "cat 1"
url:"https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/appicns/513/appicns_Chrome.png"

3:object
cat_id:3
cat_lib:"sport"
card_lib: "cat 1"
url:"https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/appicns/513/appicns_Chrome.png"

4:object
cat_id:3
cat_lib:"sport"
card_lib: "cat 2"
url:"https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/appicns/513/appicns_Chrome.png"
```

and a layout :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjhZH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this:

http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It is this tutorial that I followed it displays the same number of cards (function createDummyData ()) but I would like to know how to display categories that have fewer cards